# Converting Hour Numbers to Duration (HH:mm:ss) format DAX

Tags: excel, dax, powerquery, measure

So I have this set of data imported via PowerQuery and loaded to the Data Model of my excel workbook. To alleviate the query load time, I decided to make majority of the transformations over to the data model rather than the query editor. Now, I have a field named [Internal Time] which stores the duration between two timestamps in hour units. I want to find a way to successfully convert them to time values in HH:mm:ss format.

As you can see on the table below, some of the conversions were correct while some are way off

| Internal Time | Internal Time (Duration) |
| --- | --- |
| 47.7 | 23:42:00 |
| 8.2 | 8:12:00 |

The solution I used is to basically just divide column 1 by 24.

The full formula is below. There were a lot of conditions but for any that will be met, the value will be divided by 24.

```
=(IF([Create Time]>[Finish Time], [Create Time]-[Finish Time],
IF(AND([Internal Time]>0, [Internal Time]-[Weekends] >0), [Internal Time]-'Raw Data'[Weekends],
IF(AND([Internal Time]>0, [Internal Time]-[Weekends] <=0), [Internal Time],
IF(AND([Internal Time]<0, [Actual Duration] >0), [Actual Duration],
IF([Internal Time]=0, [Finish Time] - [Create Time]))))))/24
```

Comment: DAX doesn't have a "Duration" data type. You can use Time data format **only** if your duration will always be less than 24 hrs (a day). In your example above, the first row is technically correct but it is missing the 1 day ie 1:23:42:00, again duration data type doesn't exist in dax. What is the overall scenario or object with this Internal Time (duration)?

Comment: Thanks for responding. The internal time is basically calculated upon export which computes the total hours between date 1 and date 2. There are a lot if inconsistencies with this field which is why I resorted to using conditions. Can this be done in M Query instead? I found a solution described below:

=VAR _hours = INT([Internal Time])
VAR _minutes = ROUND(([Internal Time]-_hours)*60,0)
RETURN
_hours&":"&_minutes&":00"

While it does return the correct values, the resulting output is in text format and cannot be used in aggregations if needed.

Comment: Why not just keep it as it is? You want to keep it numeric for calculations as you said. Is `Internal Time` not calculated correctly? Yes, doing it in M Query (or Power Query) would be preferred but it depends on what you have and what you are trying to do. What's the `WEEKENDS` column/measure for in the conditional? Update your question above with more info/detail with a clear problem statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is more like a workaround.

**NOTE:** This only works until 31 days, if there is more this counter restarts.

It is based on a date format of the first of the month, in the example below 1/1/2000 and adds your measure [Internal Time]. You can then use this by showing days, hours, minutes and seconds.

```
yourMeasure = 

VAR DateHelper = DATE(2000,1,1)

Return
DateHelper + 
DATE(
    YEAR([Internal Time]/24),
        MONTH([Internal Time]/24),
        DAY([Internal Time]/24)
    )+
TIME(
    HOUR([Internal Time]/24),
    MINUTE([Internal Time]/24),
    SECOND([Internal Time]/24)
)
```

After adding this measure to the table/matrix, make sure to change the format to "d hh:mm:ss"

Comment: Hello. The issue with this is it should not be in text format. I have a similar solution but ended up not using since I cannot use it in aggregating the resulting values:

=VAR _hours = INT([Internal Time])
VAR _minutes = ROUND(([Internal Time]-_hours)*60,0)
RETURN
_hours&":"&_minutes&":00"

Comment: I updated so it can be formatted, but **note**. this is more like a workaround, best would be to add the duration column in the query editor.